# Clearing cache programmatically?

Tags: android, caching

I have already seen the other questions but i want something different and simpler(i think).

I have an activity that on click sends to the email address that you have entered a welcome email using java mail api. To be more specific when it first runs you enter your gmail account with your password and the address where the welcome email is sent. Now when i put a wrong password an exception is created and you have asked to put your real pass or username. But if i put my real one it asks me again to do that. In addition if i put my real one and then cange it it continues to send the welcome mail. How can i fix this? Here is a sample code:

```
EmailValidator val = new EmailValidator();                   

    Boolean a = val.validate(yemail);
    Boolean b = val.validate(temail);
    if (a == false || b == false){
        AlertDialog.Builder box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Set the message to display
    box.setMessage("Please enter a valid email address!");

            // Add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click listener
    box.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()        {

                // Click listener on the neutral button of alert box
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)             {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                    }                   
                                                                            });
                            box.show();
                                }// end if validating emails
    if (a == true && b == true && ypass != null){
        try { // send mail
            GmailSender sender = new GmailSender(yemail,ypass); // SUBSTITUTE HERE                
            sender.sendMail(
                                "EMERGENCY",   //subject.getText().toString(), 
                                "hi",                  //body.getText().toString(), 
                                "stathias7@hotmail.com",                      //from.getText().toString(),
                                temail //to.getText().toString() address where the mail is sent to
                            );

            } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder box = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Set the message to display
    box.setMessage("Please Re-enter your Gmail username and pasword");

            // Add a neutral button to the alert box and assign a click listener
    box.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                // Click listener on the neutral button of alert box
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                                    }                   
                                                                            });
                            box.show();
                        } // end catching Exception

                                                    } // try to send mail

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will useful to you...

```
private boolean validMail(String emailstring) {
    Pattern emailPattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
    Matcher emailMatcher = emailPattern.matcher(emailstring);
    return emailMatcher.matches();
}
```

Comment: I use a similar function to see if the input from the user is an email address, but i do not ask this.If an invalid gmail account is given an authentication exception is thrown. Then is use my true gmail account and the same message is put in front of my screen. So a second Authentication is never done. This is the thing i want to correct!

Comment: Then i think you have to clear the catche if invalid email address is given.

Comment: Ok we are geting close now. How to do this programmaticaly? I do not want the user to interfere! Lets say do that on click! Can you provide me a sample code?